# In Fabric Ledger ,Contract is not called

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I deploy a java chaincode in "fabric-sample" testnetwork. All the life cycles are sucessfully executed like (peer clifecycle chaincode package|install|approve|commit).After that chaincode is instantiaed successfully.But when try to access the chain code functions, I get the below error :

```
**Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"Undefined contract called" **
```

I used the below code to access chain code function "addNewCar" and get the following error :

[image]

Comment: Based on https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/issues/559, you have to compile the chaincode with jdk 11.

Answer (score 0):

The *"Undefined contract called"* message is returned by the Java chaincode runtime if the contract namespace specified does not exist within the chaincode. A chaincode may contain multiple smart contract definitions, each identified by a namespace. It may also contain one default smart contract, which does not have a namespace (or whose namespace is empty).

Just for reference, and by way of explanation, programmatically in a Java client application you would obtain the default smart contract for a chaincode by calling [Network.getContract(String chaincodeName)](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/main/api/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/client/Network.html#getContract(java.lang.String)). You would obtain a specific named (or namespaced) smart contract within a chaincode by calling [Network.getContract(String chaincodeName, String contractName)](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/main/api/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/client/Network.html#getContract(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

When actually invoking the chaincode, the contract name (or namespace) is prepended to the transaction function name so that the chaincode runtime can identify which smart contract should be invoked. The actual transaction name passed to invoke the **AddCar** transaction function on a smart contract named **car** would be **car:AddCar**. The **AddCar** transaction on the default (no namespace) smart contract would be invoked just using the name **AddCar**.

Using the **peer** CLI command, you need to prepend the correct smart contract name to your transaction function name in order to invoke a specific named smart contract. Your screenshot does not capture the complete CLI command you invoked but I suspect that the transaction function name you supplied does not correctly include the name of the smart contract providing that transaction function.